# How to wake up system directly to desktop view in Windows 8.1?

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1, lockscreen, wakeup, taskscheduler

**Scenario**:

1. Task Scheduler - puts a system to a sleep
2. Task Scheduler - wakes the
   system up
3. Task Scheduler - launches another program but it is vital
   that it was

**Problem**:

During the wake up procedure, a system state stops at the window namely "*Lock Screen*" which shows time and it cannot really run tasks I want after the system's wake up.

**To deal with the Lock Screen, I usually do the following**:

1. Press Enter -> takes me to ***user account selection window***
2. Press Enter again -> having one account and no password -> takes me
   to desktop.

**My thoughts so far**:

Perhaps I could execute some script which would help me send "Enter" command as input to these two states, yet, I have no clue how to do that.

**Relevant to some extent resources found by far**:

- [How to perform keystroke inside powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849522/how-to-perform-keystroke-inside-powershell)
- [Put computer in standby after running a scheduled task but only if it had to wake up to run it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765784/put-computer-in-standby-after-running-a-scheduled-task-but-only-if-it-had-to-wak)

If there are suggestions or other ideas on how to go around this Lock and User Account screens, I am grateful if you share it!

Thank you!

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, thank you for the edit. I agree that it is better this way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set autologon up so it logs directly in to the desktop.

You really need to only setup three registry keys.

I've included a link to the tech net page 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324737

Comment: Thank you Someone that matters, for suggesting me this. It works as a way out for me.